# Stop system error on standrad error

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am writing an AWK script that starts an infinite loop - hence in the script I validate presence of file in a specified path if so I would exit from the infinite loop :

```
while ( ("ls -l /tmp/STOP" |& getline var4) > 0) {
        exit 0
}
close("ls -l /tmp/STOP")
```

The issue is that I get standard error during the run time when the file is not there:

ls: /tmp/STOP: No such file or directory

How can we avoid this standard error message on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redirecting the error stream to `/dev/null`:

```
while ( ("ls -l /tmp/STOP 2>/dev/null" |& getline var4) > 0) {
    exit 0
}
close("ls -l /tmp/STOP")
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint I tried the command as "ls -l /tmp | grep STOP" and it worked perfectly with no errors reported in case file is not fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ls` if you don't particularly want a directory listing.  Something like the exit code from `test -e /tmp/STOP` would work better.

```
 if (! system ("test -e /tmp/STOP")) exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN {
  while ( system("sleep 1; test -f /tmp/STOP") ) print "The file is not there..."
  exit
}
```

The sleep command is there because you do not want to spawn processes like crazy.